# How to close child Dialog window without closing the parent Dialog window in wxPython

Tags: python, dialog, wxpython, frame, wxwidgets

I'm developing a GUI in Python (2.7) using wx (3.0.2.0).

The main frame is a Frame object and I have a button on it which pops up a Dialog window child. On this Dialog window, I also have a button which opens, again, another Dialog window child, and hides the first Dialog window (to avoid having too many windows open). Now on this last Dialog window, I have a Close button, and what I want is for this button to close the dialog and show the parent Dialog window (which has been previously hidden), without closing it.

I haven't been able to do it, everytime I close this last Dialog window, it closes the parent Dialog window too and I end up on the main frame.

Does someone have an idea of how to do this?

Here's a sample code:

```
import wx

class AST_MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)

        self.configure_project_btn = wx.Button(self, 1, "Configure 1")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_configure, id=1)

    def on_configure(self, event):
        test_frame = AST_SheetFrame(self)
        test_frame.ShowModal()
        test_frame.Destroy()


class AST_SheetFrame(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(AST_SheetFrame, self).__init__(parent, style=(wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE | wx.RESIZE_BORDER))

        self.configure_project_btn = wx.Button(self, 2, "Configure 2")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_configure, id=2)

    def on_configure(self, event):
        test_frame = AST_ModuleFrame(self)
        test_frame.ShowModal()
        test_frame.Destroy()


class AST_ModuleFrame(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(AST_ModuleFrame, self).__init__(parent, style=(wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE | wx.RESIZE_BORDER))
        self.parent = parent

        self.save_n_quit_btn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CLOSE, "Save and Close")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_quit, id=wx.ID_CLOSE)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_quit)
        self.parent.Hide()

    def on_quit(self, event):
        self.parent.Show()
        self.Destroy()


class GUI(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        app = AST_MainFrame(None, -1, "Main frame")
        app.Show(True)
        return True


def main():
    app = GUI(0)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: remove `test_frame.Destroy()` from `AST_MainFrame.on_configure`

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem!